# Многопоточность в Spring MVC

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Как создать параллельный поток в приложении реализованном на Spring MVC. Чтобы при загрузке сервера создавался новый поток, который например бы каждую минуту генерировал рандомное число и, например, можно было взять как нибудь из этого потока(Класса) число в определенное время.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого не надо запускать постоянно работающий фоновый поток, можно просто запланировать выполнение метода раз в минуту:

```
@Service
public class RandomService {
    private int randomValue;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=60000)
    public void generateValue() {
        randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100);
    }

    ...
}
```

А если постоянно работающий фоновый поток всё же нужен, то ничто не мешает объявить бином наследника `Thread` и пометить аннотацией `@PostConstruct` метод `start()`. Или подобным же образом использовать `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Comment: Можно ли в fixedDelay добавлять динамически изменяющиеся значения?

Comment: Для планирования выполнения задач в рантайме вы можете внедрить [ThreadPoolTaskScheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.html) и использовать его методы полностью аналогичные соответствующим аннотациям.

Comment: Мне как раз таки не нужен пул потоков, нужен 1 поток( скорее всего тот пример который вы показали подходит), но нужно как то изменять параметр fixedDelay можно конкретно из этого метода в котором он используется.

Comment: Почему именно один поток нужен?

Comment: Поток который работает с какими-то данными, параллельно всей программе, через заданное время (вычисляется другим способом) должен отправлять post запрос на другой сервер.

Comment: Тогда действуйте так, как описано в ответе после кода.

Comment: Да, спасибо....