# Дополнительный поток Thread реализованный в Spring Boot Rest-сервисе не работает в Tomcat 8.5.11

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

Я пишу rest-сервис и использую Spring Boot. Сервис в основном потоке получает запросы по REST, а в дополнительном проводит очистку файлов в нужное время на компьютере. В этом сервисе реализовал дополнительный поток Tread, который чистит директорию на компьютере. 
Реализовано это так:

код запуска потока и самого потока DirCleaner.java

```
Runnable task = () -> {
        try {
            while (true) {
                тут код работы очистки и условия проверки
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                    }
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException threadEx) {EventLogWriter.logEvent(EventStatus.ERROR, threadEx.getMessage()); }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            EventLogWriter.logEvent(EventStatus.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
        }
    };
    Thread delThread = new Thread(task, "Поток удалающий файлы");
    delThread.
```

Проблема в том, что на сервере Tomcat 8.5.11 этот поток не запускается, запускается только основной поток в котором работает  @Controller, хотя локально при отладки или запуске в Intellij IDEA все работает нормально, и приложение работает в 2 потока.

Код Main.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.del.api")
public class SpringApplicationsDel extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
implements WebApplicationInitializer {


public static void main(String []args){
    ApplicationContext startContext = SpringApplication.run(SpringApplicationsDel.class,args);
    DirCleaner dirCleaner = (DirCleaner) startContext.getBean("DirCleaner");
    EventLogWriter.logEvent(EventStatus.WARN, "Приложение запущено");
    dirCleaner.startRun();
}


protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder){
    EventLogWriter.logEvent(EventStatus.WARN, "Приложение запускается");
    return builder.sources(SpringApplicationsDel.class);
}
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Многопоточность в Spring MVC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786422/204271)

Comment: Дело в том, что мне нужен постоянный фоновый поток.
Я попробую наследоваться от Tread и сделать этот класс Бином, может поможет.
Просто не понятно, почему локально(при запуске из IDE) все работает как задумано, а при старте в Tomcat не работает

Comment: В том вопросе описано и как лучше запускать фоновые потоки в Spring.

Comment: Сделайте [дамп потоков](https://habr.com/company/otus/blog/427513/) Tomcat'а или подключитесь к нему отладчиком и посмотрите, что с вашим потоком происходит.

Comment: Понял, попробую. Спасибо большое за помощь. Отпишу, как попробую решение.

Comment: Вариант с наследование от Thread и запуском функции с тегом @PostConstruct помогло решить проблему, еще раз спасибо!