# Java Spring, метод работает в Controller, но не работает в моем классе

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Есть класс моего потока:

```
@Component
public class MailThread extends Thread {
@Autowired
private MessageRepo messageRepo;

public MailThread() {}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            Iterable<Message> messages;
            messages = messageRepo.findByTime("18:50");
            for(Message message : messages){
                System.out.println(message.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("minute");
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

MessageRepo:

```
public interface MessageRepo extends JpaRepository<Message, Long> {
List<Message> findByTime(String time);
}
```

Я вызываю свой поток из Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    new MailThread().run();
}
}
```

Но получаю такую ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at project.components.MailThread.run(MailThread.java:39)
at project.Application.main(Application.java:12)
... 5 mor
```

Как раз там, где пытаюсь найти все сообщения из базы данных(messages = messageRepo.findByTime("18:50")) При вызове из обычного контроллера все работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Многопоточность в Spring MVC](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786422/204271)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Аннотация `@Autowire` работает только в тех объектах, которых созданы контейнером Spring, а не оператором `new`.

Comment: Понял, а как решить проблему?

Comment: И добиться того, чтобы каждую минуту из базы данных доставались данные?

Comment: То есть, как создать объект MailThread автоматически и запустить метод run?

Comment: Почитайте про аннотацию @Schedule и не выдумывайте велосипеды

Comment: Принял, спасибо.